# Proof of identity in the sense of distributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-writing, distribution-theory, convolution

I am trying to prove this:

$\bullet$ Prove that $\Delta(\varrho_\epsilon \star u) = \varrho_\epsilon \star f $ in the sense of distributions, if $\Delta u = f$ in the sense of distributions, $ u \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance and I take advantage of the situation to wish you a happy new year :D

Comment: Please define all letters, and mention where "they" live in, also show the own attempts to solve the problem. (The $\star$ is the convolution $*$?)

Comment: Yes, it is the convolution. I thought that the laplacian is the sum of the second derivative and in the convolution with mollifiers it result to the convolution of mollifiers with the second derivative of the function $u$ which is $f$ by hypotesis. Is it the rigth way?

Answer (score 0):

The only rule you need except for linearity is $\partial_k (u*v) = u * (\partial_k v).$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\Delta u=f$ in the sense of distributions. One can easily verify that $$P (v*u)=(Pv)*u=v*(Pu)$$ in the sense of distributions for $v\in \mathcal{S},u\in\mathcal{S}'$, and any constant-coefficient differential operator $P$. If we take $P=\Delta$, $v=\rho_\epsilon,$ and $u$ to be itself, then it follows directly that
$$ \Delta (\rho_\epsilon*u)=\rho_\epsilon*(\Delta u)=\rho_\epsilon*f$$ in the sense of distributions.